# Clear current selection in a QlikView extension object

Tags: qlikview, extension-objects

I have an extension object in which I use `_this.Data.SearchColumn(0, "*" + d.name + "*",false);` to make a selection, where `_this` is the local variable that holds the reference from QlikView (`var _this = this;`).

I want to be able to clear all selections in my document when I click on a button from my extension.
I tried to use `_this.Data.ClearSelections();` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in this way:

```
var mydoc = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();

myDoc.Clear();
```